# Fill a listview without calling setContentView

Tags: android, listview, fill

I want to fill a list with some information. My problem is that I want to fill the last, at the end of an activity.

I try to explain:

```
Start -> activity1 (layout1) -> activity2 (layout2) -> end (layoutEnd)
```

Now I want to add some information to a list and I want to do this the onCreate of the end (activity). I can't setContentView to the layout of the activity, because I set that to layoutEnd.

Code end:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.training_beendet);




        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(new yourAdapter(this, new String[] { "Anfänger 1"}));
    }
```

Layout with listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout with textViews for the listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header"
    android:id="@+id/header"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/header" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve a boolean flag either in SharedPreference or in database inside MainActivity, my mean of flag is to maintain a value whether it's a fresh start or not.

- Inside onCreate() method of MainActivity, just check that boolean flag variable, if it's fresh start then launch Start activity otherwise Activity with ListView.
- If it's fresh start and you are in the end, then write an Intent to launch activity which is having listview with information.